# Programming Scheme(Racket) with VIM - How to get started

Tags: vim, lisp, scheme, racket

recently, I started programming Racket (formerly Scheme) in DrRacket.
I quite fast I began to miss all the features of VIM in DrRacket, so I would like
to use VIM for my scheme(racket) programming.

I know that Emacs might be the best choice for intense lisp programming, but all
I want is write a scheme(racket) file check syntax and then run it.

Unfortunately, I could not figure out, how to invoke "racket" in the commandline
on a file to get it doing the same as DrRacket.

I am running Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat, VIM 7.3 and I downloaded and
installed Racket from the official website.

Help to get started would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you just want to load a file into Racket on the command-line and run it, I think that this should work:

```
$ racket -f file.scm -i
```

The `-i` option would leave you at the REPL to test your code in `file.scm`.

However, you might want to take a look at this blog post:

http://technotales.wordpress.com/2007/10/03/like-slime-for-vim/

You can set up a GNU screen session running the command-line Racket, and send s-expressions to it from Vim. There's a link to a bit of Vimscript which will make this automatic. I used this for a while with mit-scheme, and it was reasonably effective. It's not quite the as powerful as SLIME or DrRacket though. I just tested the steps described on OS X and it works with the command-line racket, it should work on Ubuntu, that's what I was using when I first used this method.

You might also want to take a look at this:

http://evalwhen.com/scmindent/index.html

... which has some information on better indentation in Vim for Lisp and Scheme code.

I eventually switched to Emacs, but don't let the Vim haters get you down. Paul Graham supposedly uses vi and he's gotta be one of the top 5 most prominent Lisp programmers.

http://paul.graham.usesthis.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but running from within vim with the racket -f file -i command gives me:
reference to undefined identifier: check-expect
Is check-expect only DrRacket?

Comment: ok thanks i figured out to add
#lang scheme
(require htdp/testing)
(check-expect 1 2)
(generate-report)

Comment: Sorry I hadn't thought about that `#lang` specifier, I usually use Racket in R5RS mode. Glad you got it to work though!

Comment: The evalwhen link shows a Japanese spam page.

Answer (score 17):

Several add-ons are available to make coding in Racket more satisfying with Vim.

- Vim’s lisp mode (`set lisp`) -- improves some basics for indenting and `w`/`e`/`b` word-hopping.
- [vim-racket](https://github.com/wlangstroth/vim-racket) -- sizable set of vim-syntax recognition for functions and syntax
- [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) -- identify errors upon save (vim-racket sets `makeprg` for this to work)
- [Rainbow Parentheses](https://github.com/kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim) -- set your own paren colors for maximal contrast!
- [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime) -- use with [Tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) to connect Vim to a Racket REPL
- [surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) -- wrap forms and elements in parens
- [vim-sexp for normal people](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people)
- [Molokai color scheme](https://github.com/tomasr/molokai) -- high contrast
- [VROD](https://github.com/MicahElliott/vrod)* -- `K`-based Vim documenation, and auto-completion of Racket functions
- [REPTL](https://github.com/MicahElliott/reptl)* -- very simple continuous rackunit test runner

I prefer slime over slimv for its simplicity.

If you are using [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim), here is a way to install most of the add-ons mentioned:

```
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround.git'
Plugin 'kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic.git'
Plugin 'MicahElliott/vrod'
Plugin 'guns/vim-sexp'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people'
Plugin 'wlangstroth/vim-racket'
Plugin 'tomasr/molokai.git'
```

Put those into your `~/.vimrc`, and then invoke to install:

```
% vim +PluginInstall +qall
```

Here is a screenshot showing off most of these:

[image]

*(* disclosure: I wrote VROD and REPTL, and they are immature)*

Also, [here is a related blog post](http://crash.net.nz/posts/2014/08/configuring-vim-for-sicp/) describing a Vim/SICP setup.

Comment: [Paredit](https://github.com/kovisoft/paredit) is also useful for structured editing and making sure that there are no unbalanced parentheses. Slimv includes paredit; this is the standalone version.

Answer (score 2):

As of about a week ago, [SLIMV](https://bitbucket.org/kovisoft/slimv) (SLIME for Vim) supports Racket. SLIMV is generally regarded as the most mature Lisp environment for Vim at the moment.