# Little Schemer and Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, the-little-schemer

I'm starting to read the Little Schemer and now instead of PLT Scheme we have Racket. I would like to know if Racket is suitable for doing the exercises in the book or do I need to get another true Scheme compiler. Before I forgot to tell you, my OS is Windows x64.

The book, language and paradigm is complex enough, I would love to avoid struggling with a compiler.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

DrRacket is the (r)evolution of DrScheme; DrRacket will work perfectly for the exercises in "The Little Schemer". Just don't forget to:

1. In the `Language` dialog, choose "Use the language declared in the source"
2. Write `#lang racket` at the top of each file you create
3. Implement the `atom?` predicate in each file as explained at the very beginning of the book
4. If you're going to re-implement an existing procedure, do so in a separate tab or window, because trying to rewrite a procedure in the edit window will result in a `duplicate definition for identifier` error. If necessary, use several files for saving the procedure definitions

Comment: Gracias Óscar, un abrazo desde Argentina.

Comment: Con mucho gusto! Acabo de editar mi respuesta, tiene varios tips adicionales para usar DrRacket con The Little Schemer

Comment: I've been using racket, but I note that I have to change all the examples to include quote. Like you can't just enter (coffee cup tea cup and hick cup), it has to be '(coffe cup tea cup and hick cup), with the leading quote.

Answer (score 9):

You really just need the `atom?` function. What’s described in the book's preface is essentially:

```
(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (pair? x)) (not (null? x))))
```

As mentioned, it should satisfy this test:

```
(atom? '()) ;=> #f
```

Note that there is also a definition in [Racklog](http://docs.racket-lang.org/racklog/index.html) that *will not satisfy that test*.

A more detailed discussion on `atom?` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404707/check-if-an-argument-is-a-list-or-an-atom).

Despite the book's suggestion to implement `add1` and `sub1`, Racket *does* already provide them.

BTW, I use [Vim for editing Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31999765/326516), but [a few other editors are capable](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/other-editors.html).

Comment: Not sure; probably no relevance. I just stumbled across it while looking for an atom? func. Was easy to try out but saw that it wouldn't work, so thought worth the warning.

Answer (score 7):

I have had the author of the book as a professor. He now uses Racket himself, but he uses Emacs as a text editor.

Answer (score 2):

Racket/Scheme are interchangeable. You should be able to answer any exercise with it.  Good luck.

Also, I recommend downloading Dr. Racket as your interpreter.