# Force Vim to align params in Lisp

Tags: vim, scheme, lisp

I am in a computer science class that requires that Lisp style look like this:

```
(define append (as bs)
  (if (null? as)
      bs
      (cons (car as)
            (append (cdr as) bs))))
```

instead of like this:

```
(define append (as bs)
  (if (null? as)
    bs
    (cons (car as)
          (append (cdr as) bs))))
```

Namely, the if branches should be aligned. Is there a way to force Vim to do this?

Comment: Not really helpful if you really want to use vim, but the example you gave is formatted as you wish with the Scheme mode of Emacs (with default configuration).

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1cij7/ask_reddit_best_way_to_edit_scheme_in_vim/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5352997/124319

Comment: @coredump thank you but I do not need fancy features like that -- just different indentation.

Comment: See also https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Vim.html

Comment: @coredump that seems like the reverse; I want it to change the behavior of current lispwords.

Comment: That's a rather strange requirement from your course, considering that the not aligned branches are "standard" (at least for Common Lisp and AFAIK)

Comment: @DanielJour I'll go back and check the requirements specifically but I think that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want Vim's Lisp mode to treat all forms as function calls, so that items of a multi-line expression align with the second element, then simply clear the `lispwords` parameter:

```
:set lispwords=
```

From your exmaple, you do seem to want a split `define` to be treated with indentation rather than alignment. Figure out the set of forms for which you want indenting rather than aligning behavior and put that exact set into your `lispwords`:

```
:set lispwords=define[,... whatever other symbols]
```

This can be done based on file type with an auto-loaded. In your `.vimrc` file you can have:

```
:au BufRead,BufNewFile *.scm set lispwords=define
```

After putting that in my `.vimrc` temporarily, if I edit a new file:

```
$ vim foo.scm
```

and then insert a few lines, they get automatically formatted like thisL

```
(define fun ()
  (if foo
      (then ...)
      (else ...)
~
~
~
:q!
```

I just hit Enter there; the auto-indentation kicked in. Vim's config already associates `.scm` files with Scheme and sets up Lisp mode. Our `au` command customizes that by overriding `lispwords`.